# Como criar tags em XML a partir do nome das colunas de um banco mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Como fazer para criar as tags do XML com o nome das colunas de uma tabela vinda de uma query myslq?

No código que fiz consigo apenas pegar os valores de cada célula da tabela, mas o que eu queria era criar as tags automaticamente de acordo com cada coluna.

[Meu código atual](http://paste.ofcode.org/xAgu7avFTabiLCDGWkHj7e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para listar o nome da suas colunas no mysql vc utiliza o seguinte comando

```
$sql = "desc NomeDaTabela";
$result = @mysql_query($sql);
while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row[0]."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o *[information schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html)* para obter os nomes das colunas de sua tabela.

Um exemplo que você pode aplicar é [esse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526688/get-table-column-names-in-mysql):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'testes' AND TABLE_NAME = 'testes';
```